# Maps between skyscraper sheafs and line bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{C}$, $x \in C$ is a point, $k(x)$ is a skyscraper sheaf at his point, $L$ is some line bundle, why
$$
Hom(k(x), L) \cong 0 ?
$$
Is this (or some analogs) true for higher dimensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We only need that $C$ is of positive dimension. The vanishing of a homomorphism of sheaves can be checked locally. Besides, the support of $k(x)$ is $\{x\}$ (I assume that your point is closed). Thus, the claim reduces to: If $A$ is an integral domain, which is not a field, and $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal of $A$, then $\hom_A(A/\mathfrak{m},A)=0$. Well, $\hom_A(A/\mathfrak{m},A)$ is isomorphic to $\{a \in A : \mathfrak{m}a=0\}$, and since $\mathfrak{m} \neq 0$ and $A$ has no zero divisors, this is trivial.

Comment: Thanks, I confused myself with example $A=\mathbb{C}[x]$ and natural embedding $\mathbb{C} \to A$, but this not a map of modules...